# 'Cannot find type 'GADInterstitialAd' in scope' error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob, ads

Hello I am getting this error when archiving my app on XCode. The app runs correctly on Simulator and on a Physical Device, but when I try to archive I get this error:

> Cannot find type 'GADInterstitialAd' in scope

This is pod file:

> pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK','~>8.0'

I import Google ads as well like so:

> import GoogleMobileAds

This is interstitial implementation:

```
GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID: NSLocalizedString("interstitial_id", comment: ""), request: request, completionHandler: {[weak self] (ad, error) in
        if error != nil {
            return
        }
        self!.interstitial = ad
        self!.interstitial.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
    })
```

Comment: Why self is force unwrapped?

Answer (score 0):

You are propably using legacy API for intersticial Ad. Google sometimes changes the API without properly telling everyone..

Try implementing new Intersticial Ad API where you use `GAMInterstitialAd.load` instead of `GADInterstitialAd.load` .

Here is documentation for new api : [Google Intersticial API link](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/interstitial)

Comment: I updated the implementation but still the same issue: `Cannot find type 'GAMInterstitialAd' in scope`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by moving Pods to trash manually because `pod deintegrate` didn't work and I reinstalled pods all from scratch. Then I added the Google Ads SDK frameworks to `Link Binary With Libraries` manually.